# How to add data to a TreeGrid component

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I have used the TreeGrid component (without defining a root) and i would like to know how to add data. I use smartgwt in eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to populate your tree grid.

```
TreeGrid treeGrid = new TreeGrid();

Tree data = new Tree();
data.setModelType(TreeModelType.CHILDREN);
data.setRoot(new TreeNode("root", new TreeNode("File"), new TreeNode("Edit"), new TreeNode(
    "Search"), new TreeNode("Project"), new TreeNode("Tools"), new TreeNode("Window"),
    new TreeNode("Favourites")));

treeGrid.setData(data);
```